KeyCloak authentication CORS issue using Jumbojett
I try to configure OIDC using the JumboJett library in my PHP application. I started to test first using a simple PHP script and it's all working perfectly. Then I try to integrate it in my application login flow (Angular + PHP).
And then I have the following error when launching JumboJett authentication
Reason : CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » is missing. Code : 405
The only difference is that JumboJett is launching in backend after a REST API call from the front.
In my keycloak administration, I setup the Web Origins like the following. I try only the * and still the same error

Do you have any ideas of what I miss ?
Thanks
